# Render value from function in component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component in React like this:

```
const myAge = () => {
  var diff = Date.now() - new Date(1991, 2, 1);
  var age = new Date(diff);
  return age;
};
export const About = (props) => {
  return (
      <Container id={props.id}>
         <p> My age is: {myAge}</p>
      </Container>
  )
}
```

I want the result of the function `myAge` to be returned and rendered in the `p` tag, but nothing is rendered. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any suggestions? Ty.

Comment: You have to call myAge, like this `{myAge()}`

Comment: I tryied that but this error happend:  ``Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Mon Jul 24 1995 16:02:22 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Arg)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.``

Comment: React expects a string, and a Date is not a string, you can cast it by saying `return String(age)` or another way if you want to format it some specific way

Comment: Yes that work, if u want answer and I give the best answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the function, that is `{myAge()}`
and then the `new Date(diff)` is not a string, so you have to cast it like this `return String(age)`